# Sympy cannot solve my equation and gets stuck

Tags: sympy, symbols, solver

I have a simple equation, trying to solve for using symbolic, however the code gets stuck and I do not get an error for me to debug. How can I do this correctly?

```
from sympy import *

from sympy import init_printing
init_printing(use_latex = True)
import sympy as sp
from numpy import random
import numpy as np
import math

from decimal import *

timeS = symbols("t")

eq1 =  Eq( (-4221.4125*exp(-2750.0*timeS)*sin(6514.4071*timeS) + 10000.0*exp(-2750.0*timeS)*cos(6514.4071*timeS)),8000)
T_off = solve(eq1,  timeS  )[0]
display("T_off = ",T_off)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation looks like one that doesn't have an analytic solution so you should use `nsolve` instead. There is a root between `-0.001` and `0` so the bisect method gives:

```
In [59]: nsolve(eq1, timeS, [-0.001, 0])
Out[59]: 3.46762014687136e-5
```

Comment: I didn't know you could select bisection by just using a range for the guess -- that's nice. But it should not -- if using bisection -- given a root outside of the range for the guess.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I was not able to find information on nsolve, can you point me in the right direction? Also why did you say there is a root  between -0.001 and 0 but the solver found the answer in between 0 and 0.001 ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the root was out of range. I guess there's also a positive root then

Answer (score 0):

This is an ill-posed equation. Rescale by dividing both sides by `10**4` and replace `timeS` with `Symbol(x)/10**4` and use `nsolve`

```
>>> eq2 = eq1.func(eq1.lhs/10**4, eq1.rhs/10**4).subs(timeS, symbols('x')/10**4)
>>> from sympy import nsolve
>>> nsolve(eq2,0)
0.346762014687135
```

So `timeS ~= 0.35e-4`. The `sqrt` function automatically scales sums so `sqrt(eq1.rewrite(Add))` will reduce coefficients of the terms to something less than 1 but such simplification is not part of SymPy simplification of general epxressions at present.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, how did you determine so quickly that the equation was ill posed? And I did not understand why you mention the sqrt I did not see it as part of your solution.  Also how did you determine to rescale both sides by 10**4 and not power of 5 or 6?  Thanks again

Comment: The scaling just helps you use numbers closer to 1 to do your guessing -- the actual value doesn't matter. Graph `sin(1000*x)` and `sin(x)` and think about trying to find a maximum to the right of 0. Solvers often have default settings for testing the function that assume it is not too rapidly changing in the region in which you are testing. Even bisection can run into problems with scaling, however, since it has to decide when the answer is close enough to zero.